# Предложение правильно ли составлено по смыслу и пунктуации?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография, запятые, синтаксис

Мрачные облака застывшие над деревней, медленно растворялись в свете луны, расползаясь по всему небу бесформенными клочками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем предложении пропущена запятая перед "застывшие", а она должна открывать определительный оборот (см. правило [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC/)). В остальном огрехов не вижу.

Верно будет так.

*Мрачные облака, застывшие над деревней, медленно растворялись в свете луны, расползаясь по всему небу бесформенными клочками.*